# When a row is selected in the table, do something on the other table?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, row, nsmutabledictionary

I have three tables in a view, I need to implement this kind of structure;

I need to control if the row is selected in the first table, then adding rows of the third table to other view. when i press the button, the data of the selected and the rows in the third table added to view will be sent.

Firstly, i am unable to recognize whether the row is selected or not,

Secondly, when i try just to check it works, my data dictionary sent is empty, that should not.

My code is as below;

```
-(void) shareComment : (id)sender
{

int ndx = [[tableViewPharmName indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
ProdForLiterature *temp = [pharmsTable objectAtIndex:ndx];

    [sendData setObject:temp.productID forKey:@"ProductName"];
    [sendData setObject:temp.productName forKey:@"ProductId"];

    NSMutableArray *customerId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(DoctorListCell *cell in tableViewDoctorName.visibleCells)
    {
        if([cell.plusButton isHidden])
        {
            if(cell.customerId!=nil)
            {
                [customerId addObject:cell.customerId];

            }
        }

    }

    [sendData setObject:customerId forKey:@"CustomerId"];

  }
```

Comment: try didSelectRowAtIndexPath and show some more code

Comment: Your question is kind of incomplete... Show more code...And please do correct the flow of question you have asked.

Comment: which part of the code you want me to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question. To know if a row is selected you can use this method.

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
int rowSelected = path.row
```

For the second question, try first logging the temp object to see if it is empty.

```
NSLog(@"temp:%@",temp);
```

Also, check after this line.

```
[sendData setObject:customerId forKey:@"CustomerId"];
```

With another log to see if sendData contains information or it is initialised.

```
NSLog(@"sendData:%@",sendData);
```

Let us know what results you get.

Comment: i have one item in my table, when i take the NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
int rowSelected = path.row it is zero, if i take it again without selecting the row physically it is again zero, how to difference between

Comment: If the user hasn't selected anything, it actually returns nil (Apple's docs: An index path identifying the row and section indexes of the selected row or nil if the index path is invalid.). Remember that sending a message to nil is allowed, and in this case [path row] is returning 0 because path is nil. **Checking that the object returned from indexPathForSelectRow isn't nil should solve the issue.**

Comment: @erdemgc If the answer was useful, please accept the answer so it can help others. Thanks!